# enumitem: using label for a defined item

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumitem, cleveref

Whenever I try to label an item that is defined, it never seems to work.  For example, consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item[3.1]
  \item[6.3]
  \label{prob63}
  \item
    From \cref{prob63}, some statement
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this may be partly because one can use non-counter-style entries when using the optional argument to `\item[<stuff>]`. So, in that regard, you can set this manually so that the reference appears as you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcreflabel}[1]{%
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][#1][\cref@result]%
    #1}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{prob1}
  \item[6.3] \setcreflabel{6.3}\label{prob63}
  \item
    From \cref{prob63}, some statement; From \cref{prob1}, some statement.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The motivation here is to update `\cref@currentlabel` in an analogous way to how `\refstepcounter` updates `\@currentlabel`. In that way, when you issue `\label`, the correct reference content is written to the `.aux`:

```
\relax 
\newlabel{prob1}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{prob1@cref}{{[enumi][1][]1}{1}}
\newlabel{prob63}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{prob63@cref}{{[enumi][6.3][]6.3}{1}}
```

Comment: I am seeing `From ?? 6.3` and the error message is still undefined label.

Comment: @dustin: When you compile my minimal example?

Comment: In my real document where I had this issue.

Comment: @dustin: Are you calling `\setcreflabel{<something>}`?

Comment: Yes, I placed that before the `\label{}` as in the example.

Comment: @dustin: Then you'll have to update your example code to highlight this, as I don't know where things be going awry.

Comment: I have `\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref}` loaded would this be affecting it?

Comment: @dustin: Most likely, since [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) deals with cross-referencing in LaTeX. When dealing with cross-referencing problems, always consider including that you're using `hyperref`. Always. I'll look into this further later.

Comment: @dustin: The loading order should be [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) *first* then [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) (see [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764)). Also issue `\phantomsection` at the start of `\setcreflabel`.

Comment: The packages are loaded correctly.  I will try the phantomsection in a bit.

Comment: `\phantomsection` didnt work.

Comment: @dustin: Then I don't know what to do. I added your `hyperref` setup *before* loading `cleverref` and I'm not getting `??`. Please provide a minimal example that replicates your problem.